# Deep copy vs. List Comprehension

Tags: python, logic, python-module, deep-copy

I'm relatively new to programming and I'm stuck at understanding something, that appears to be very fundamental about cloning objects in Python.

Let's say we have the following code without using the deepcopy module:

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
copy = [x for x in nested_list]
```

Now if we do something like:

```
copy[1] = [9999999]
```

Then it would return the following:

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
copy = [[1, 2, 3], [9999999], [7, 8, 9]]
```

However if we were to modify only a single element within one of the nested lists such as:

```
copy[0][1] = 9999999
```

Then both the original and the copy variables would return the same value:

```
nested_list = [[1, 9999999, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
copy = [[1, 9999999, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Why is it exactly that when we give the nested list a new value it works just fine but when we give a new value to an item within the nested list, it also changes the original? Calling the id() function on both variables **nested_list** and **copy** indicates that they are separate objects, at least from my understanding.

E.G:

```
copy = nested_list                # copy and nested_list share the same id()
copy = [x for x in nested_list]   # now they have different id()
copy = deepcopy(nested_list)      # again they have different id()
```

I know that an alternative solution would be a deepcopy function, however due to it being extremely slow, I was wondering if there is any other solution to this?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: Isn't it a fun feature of python...? Something I still have trouble with and can't even explain fully.

Comment: @goalie1998. Not just python. Any language that uses pointers, regardless of what you call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sallow copy that happening by `copy = [x for x in nested_list]` is creating a new object of copy with a different `id()` then `nested_list` but all the nested lists inside of it have the same id's as the lists inside both of the lists.

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
copy = [x for x in nested_list]
print(id(copy)) #54769064
print(id(nested_list)) #54546184
print([id(i) for i in copy]) #[58832096, 58831816, 58619384]
print([id(i) for i in nested_list]) #[58832096, 58831816, 58619384]
```

When doing deep copy `copy = deepcopy(nested_list)` the copy nested lists while creating new lists with new id's that when assigning a new value to one of the nested lists like `copy[0][1] = 9999999` will change only the copy first list item and not the `nested_list[0][1]` value.

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
copy = deepcopy(nested_list)
copy[0][1] = 9999999
print(copy) #[[1, 9999999, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(nested_list) #[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, now I understand better! Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

The sublists of both `copy` as well as `nested_list` are the same location in memory. And all the corresponding sublists same id. Thats why you have this behaviour.

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
copy = [x for x in nested_list]
print(id(copy[0]) == id(nested_list[0])) #True
print(id(copy) == id(nested_list)) #False
```

If you know the `sublists` that you are going to change in advance then its possible to take deepcopy of that sublist only, to speed up the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from which programming language you are coming from, but variable reference works differently in python. I would recommend you to read this article which clearly tells.
https://www.python-course.eu/python3_deep_copy.php

I also wrote one Medium [post](https://probhakar-95.medium.com/are-python-functions-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference-6d28991df1b1?source=your_stories_page-------------------------------------) regarding variable reference. You can check it out.

Basically, what is happening when you have a list of list, then doing

```
copy[1] = [9999999]
```

is actually changing the first level reference. But when you go deeper like

```
copy[0][1] = 9999999
```

then you are altering the elements at a deeper level than reference you have not copied yet. Think of it as a tree. The copy function is like a shallow copy, when you perform the shallow copy, you just copying and making another object of the first referance. But 2nd, 3rd onwards remains the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it's all more clear now. I will check your article too. Have a great day